# Crop API Ordnance Survey map to working area size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, ordnance-survey

I'm new to QGIS. I have downloaded the Leisure 27700 Ordnance Survey map.  But I want to crop it to just the area I am working on. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: How are you obtaining this data, by WMS from the OS Data Hub for example?